# colour one row of antd table based on condition

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd

I'm using antd table in my project. I want to change the color of one row of table if *IsDefaultAccount = true*  where *IsDefaultAccount* is from back end

The code of the table in the **index.js** page is :

```
<Table
                    className="table-layout"
                    columns={this.state.columns}
                    dataSource={filteredData}
                    rowClassName='data-row'
                    bordered={true}
                    size={"small"}
                    onRowDoubleClick={ (record, index, event) => this.handleEditModal(record) }
                    onRowClick={(record, index, event) => this.handleRowClick(record)}
                    loading={this.state.loading}
                    pagination={{ pageSize: 14 }}
                />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that each data-item consists of a `IsDefaultAccount` property:

```
<Table
  className="table-layout"
  columns={this.state.columns}
  dataSource={filteredData}
  rowClassName={(record) => record.IsDefaultAccount ? 'data-row active-row' : 'data-row' }
  bordered={true}
  size={"small"}
  onRowDoubleClick={ (record, index, event) => this.handleEditModal(record) }
                    onRowClick={(record, index, event) => this.handleRowClick(record)}
  loading={this.state.loading}
  pagination={{ pageSize: 14 }}
/>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: The code is working 
Let me ask you one thing , "data-row active-row" , 'data-row' are these two styles?

Comment: `data-row` would have your common row style rules which I am assuming would be the same for active and inactive rows. `active-row` should only be applied to the rows of which you wanna change the color. In your case, `IsDefaultAccount`. Please do upvote if the code works for you.

Comment: Perfect  Answer +100!

Comment: This doesn't work as of 3.26.7 (Jan 2020).

A solution is just to create your own css class e.g. `my-active-row` instead of using `active-row`